# How to put a function inside VideoFileClip ()?

Tags: python, moviepy

In my current directory I have a **file.mp4**.

**Problem:**
I want to search the name of that file and then put file.mp4 in the `VideoFileClip('file.mp4')`.

How can I do that? I get an error when I run the code below, because `VideoFileClip()` accepts only String. **How can we put search function inside a function**?

**My code:**

```
from glob import glob
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip(glob("*.mp4"))
s = clip.duration
clip.close()
```

I also tried replacing:

```
clip = VideoFileClip( glob("*.mp4") )
```

with this alternative:

```
clip = VideoFileClip( str(glob("*.mp4")) )
```

Comment: What is `VideoFileClip`? Is this part of some third-party library/framework? Or is this a custom class..?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: from glob import glob ----->
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip ----->
clip = VideoFileClip(glob("*.mp4")) ------->
s=clip.duration ------->
clip.close() --------->
I face with error when I run this. because VideoFileClip () accepts only string.

Comment: I want to search in a current directory. then find the file.mp4. and finally I put the name of file.mp4 in the VideoFileClip (). This is my problem.

Comment: from glob import glob -----> from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip -----> clip = VideoFileClip(str(glob("*.mp4"))) -------> s=clip.duration -------> clip.close() ---------> I also tried this one. however, the error is still exist.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How can we put search function inside a function"*

You don't put a "search function inside a function".

- First you get the **result** of a search function (put it into a variable).
- Then you use that same result (the variable) as the **input** of some other function.

See if a code logic like below is closer to achieving what you want (ps: code is untested):

```
import glob
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

## Glob gives back an Array (is a list with String for each file's name)
file_list = glob.glob("*.mp4")
print("found MP4 file(s) :", file_list)

## From the Array list, now select the specific String you want to use with some function
## Test by getting the first filename's String (is at position 0 inside the list)
my_file_str = file_list[0]
print("Using this file String :", my_file_str)

clip = VideoFileClip( my_file_str)
sec = clip.duration
print("sec (clip.duration) :", sec, "seconds")
clip.close()
```